# Automation test fails due to login problem

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cypress, e2e-testing, pageobjects

I writing an e2e test automation for some application that requiere also a log in test.

BeaforeEach test i perform the login test, at the first it block the test passes

But at the second it block, after the beaforeach block exceute it seems that i logged out from the application and therefore the 2nd it block fails...

If i combine the It block into one the test is pass

this is the code :

```
const homePgae = new HomePage();
const loginPage = new LoginPage();
const explorePage = new ExplorePage()

context("empty spec", () => {
    beforeEach("starting to automate", () => {
        loginPage.navigate();
        loginPage.enterUsername();
        loginPage.enterPassword();
        loginPage.ClickLogin();
    });

    it("Test 1 Home Pgae and Explore", () => {
        homePgae.assert_links_after_login();
        homePgae.assert_text();
        homePgae.assert_buttons_after_login();
        
    });

    it("Test 2 Explore Page", () => {
        explorePage.navigate();
        explorePage.addSummaryToExistLP();
        explorePage.addSummaryToNewLP();
    });
});
```

loginPage code :

```
navigate() {
        cy.visit("/login");
    }

    enterUsername() {
        cy.get(this.loginPage_username).type(email);
    }

    enterPassword() {
        cy.get(this.loginPage_pass).type(password);
    }

    ClickLogin() {
        cy.get(this.loginPage_btn).click();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `loginPage` code so we can see more of the picture?

Comment: I understand why i logged out, after the ClickLogin method cypress responds very fast and after that navigating to other route. I need to wait for this POST request after login click : testing-api.something.com/login - How can i do that with cypress ?

Comment: Good to know you figured out the reason. For waiting on an request to complete, you will first need to intercept it and `cy.intercept()` will be of good use. I recommend checking out the docs for the different uses, but for your case it may be as simple as `cy.intercept('POST', 'api.something.com/login').as('call')` and then later on `cy.wait('@call')` to wait for it to complete. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests#Stubbing

Answer (score 3):

I can't see why that would happen, but you could try it with a `cy.session()` wrapper around the login.

```js
const homePgae = new HomePage();
const loginPage = new LoginPage();
const explorePage = new ExplorePage()

context("empty spec", () => {

    beforeEach("starting to automate", () => {
      cy.session('login', () => {
        loginPage.navigate();
        loginPage.enterUsername();
        loginPage.enterPassword();
        loginPage.ClickLogin();
      })
    });

    it("Test 1 Home Pgae and Explore", () => {
        homePgae.assert_links_after_login();
        homePgae.assert_text();
        homePgae.assert_buttons_after_login();
        
    });

    it("Test 2 Explore Page", () => {
        explorePage.navigate();
        explorePage.addSummaryToExistLP();
        explorePage.addSummaryToNewLP();
    });
})
```

The `cy.session()` preserves all browser internal state that is set during the login process. That includes cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage values.

If something in the test steps is causing the login to fail, this may overcome the problem.

Normally a web page will not permit a user to log in once they are already logged in, so adding the `cy.session()` wrapper makes the login only occur once, and just restores the state each time `beforeEach()` is called.

Comment: I understand why i logged out, after the ClickLogin method cypress responds very fast and after that navigating to other route. I need to wait for this POST request after login click : https://testing-api.something.com/login - How can i do that with cypress ?